# How to use lit-element in Visual Studio ASP.NET Core app with Polymer

Tags: asp.net-core, polymer, lit-element

I have an app developed with Visual Studio ASP.NET Core and Polymer 2 for the frontend.
The app has worked well for the previous year but now I need to add new functions.
The newest Polymer documentation recommends to either update to Polymer 3 or use lit-element as the base class for new webcomponents.

The problem is: lit-element uses JavaScript module specifiers without any path information (f.e. import { TemplateResult } from 'lit-html'). The Polymer development server changes these specifiers to the correct path during development. The development server of ASP.NET Core (Kestrel), however, passes the module import specifiers without any change to the browser but the browser (Chrome in my test) tells me:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit-html". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Note: I already changed the import specifier of lit-element in my own code to the actual path such that it works. But the above error comes from lit-element itself!

I think it's not a solution that I change all the specifiers in all the dependencies manually (which would be overridden with every update). Also I think it's not a solution to run a Polymer build every time I want to debug my application (the Polymer build might take up to one minute!)

So my question is: how do you debug with Polymer Lit-Element in Visual Studio?

Comment: lit-element is designed to be run in a node runtime (like the polymer build server for example). lit-html would resolve to a module in your package.json. I think if you want to use it in your server rendered pages, the expected pattern would be to build the lit-element components into web-components and then import those and use them that way. If you want to keep your old pattern, I think you will need to stick to Polymer 3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I don't render pages on the server. It is a "single page" application that uses a REST interface to communicate with the server. The problem is that it would be hard to mock all the data queried by the frontend from the server. With Polymer 2 it was easy to develop because I could simply run the application in Visual Studio and directly test it in Chrome without any build step before publishing it. With Polymer 3 I have to always build the client to replace the module specifiers with the actual paths to make it work. The build step needs at least a minute :-(

Comment: In the meantime I found several discussions about this at the Polymer Github page. Looks like this is a general problem that is currently unsolvable - at least until the next standard gives us something better.

Comment: Yes I understand the pain, we have a similar issue using Polymer 3/LitElement at my work. We've managed some custom solutions to shave off build-time and even some new stuff to skip the build step using npm link to a local development repo of a component. It is still not awesome. I hope that we some improvement in this workflow in future versions of Polymer project frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend either using a bundler like Rollup with the node-resolve plugin, and/or using a Node-based dev server like es-dev-server and proxying requests for JS resources to it from your .NET server for development. Rollup has a watch mode that can do incremental builds for faster dev turnaround.

Comment: Ok, that might work, I will try it. Another hour reading up on another build tool :-(  ;-)